# Using timepicker for vuejs from eleme.io

Tags: javascript, frameworks, vue.js

I tried using timepicker (Arbitrary time picker) from

http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/time-picker

But the scroll bar doesn't show up. It just shows one row of number with the scroll bar full size. See picture below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brOsj.png)

Anyone used this element before? How did you make the scrolling work?